# jni.h not found (Building VBox on 20.04)

Tags: java, virtualbox

i'm trying to build VirtualBox-6.1.6 from source. on Ubuntu 20.04 (please do not talk about precompiled i'm looking for a solution to THIS problem). 
i'm getting a compile error from kmk.

```
nsAppFileLocProviderProxy.h:42:10: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
42 | #include "jni.h"
```

however i have more then one copy..

```
locate jni.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec/jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h
```

is it an issue using openjdk vs the sun/ one? some line i need to change in the AutoConfig.kmk?

Answer (score 2):

The virtual box [build script searches for Java on Linux like this](https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/vbox/trunk/Config.kmk?rev=83708#L2749):

```
     ifeq ($(KBUILD_TARGET),linux)
      ifeq ($(origin VBOX_JAVA_HOME),undefined)
       # Add correct detection for you distro after the /usr/../java-6-sun line.
       VBOX_JAVA_HOME := $(firstword $(wildcard \
            $(KBUILD_DEVTOOLS)/linux.x86/jdk1.6.0_27 \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun  \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386 \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64 \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386 \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 \
            /usr/lib/jvm/default-java \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java \
            \
            /usr/lib/jvm/sun-jdk-1.6 \
            ) /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun)
      endif
     endif
```

Your paths (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`) don't appear in that list. So it doesn't look for `jni.h` there.

My immediate thought is to add your OpenJDK 8 path in there:

```
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386 \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 \
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 \     <<<< ADD This
            /usr/lib/jvm/default-java \
```

Then try re-building. If that works, maybe even send Virtual box maintainers the fix?

Answer (score 0):

ah.. i manged to solve it, i found a old listing of other dependencies and added a bunch java-common was one, for some reason my cmdline did not save that cmd so i cannot reproduce it. however i still only have the jni.h in my mentioned locations... nevertheless, i then had to rerun 
`./configure` and then `env.sh` script and it seemed to solve it. and it complied..